# Dockerfile Build arguments not passed to sed

Tags: docker, sed

I have the following Dockerfile.PROD, that builds my Nodejs application to then be copied over the Nginx.

I am trying to pass credentials using build arguments to Docker to then use inside a sed command to create a .env file for Nodejs use.

**My Dockerfile.PROD**

```
# build environment
FROM node:12.5.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY DEFAULT.env ./.env
RUN sed -i "s/access-key/$REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY_ID/" ./.env
RUN sed -i "s/secret-key/$REACT_APP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY/" ./.env
RUN npm ci --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
# new
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**My DEFAULT.env file**

```
REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY_ID="access-key"
REACT_APP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="secret-key"
```

**My Build command used**

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.prod  --build-arg REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ABCDEFGHZXCV --build-arg REACT_APP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=ABCDEFGHZXCVhdhjshdjsdf9889 -t test:prod .
```

**The build command keeps warning:**

> One or more build-args [REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY_ID
> REACT_APP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY] were not consumed.

For some reason the sed command is not picking them up, so must be sed syntax. I am open to other possibilities of creating the .env file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define arguments inside your Dockerfile before it's usage, using `ARG`:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg